# Finitely Additive Homogeneous Translation Invariant Measure on $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, hahn-banach-theorem

IMPORTANT EDIT: this question has been moved to [Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/323946/finitely-additive-homogeneous-translation-invariant-measure-on-mathcalp-mat)

It is known that there exists a finitely additive translation invariant measure on $\mathbb{R}$ that extends the Lebesgue measure. I.e. a function $m:\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow [0,\infty]$ that is

1) Finitely additive: $m(A \sqcup B) = m(A) + m(B)$

2) For a Lebesgue measurable set $A$, $m(A)$ is it's Lebesgue measure.

3) for all $A \subset \mathbb{R}$, $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $m(A + \lambda) = m(A)$

The proof can be found in Stein & Shakarachi's Functional Analysis (the main tool is the Hahn Banach Theorem, which gives the "Banach Integral").
This got me wondering: **can we also find such *m* that is homogeneous?** Meaning $\forall \lambda \in \mathbb{R}, \, A \subset \mathbb{R} \;  m(\lambda A) = \vert \lambda \vert m(A)$. I couldn't see directly from the proof how to do so, and since we can't use continuity of $\sigma$ additive measures, we can't use continuity arguments. Does such measure even exist? Any reference given is appreciated.

A similar statement in $\mathbb{R}^3$ fails because of the Banach-Tarski Paradox.